# Segurança em consultas com Redis e MongoDB e NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis

No modelo relacional, ao utilizar SQL temos que ter atenção com SQL Injection em nossa aplicação.

No Redis e no MongoDB, quais os cuidados que devo ter na hora de construir uma consulta ao banco de dados?

Lembrando que estou a usar NodeJs, mas penso que se aplica a qualquer linguagem.

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando PHP, sim, você pode sofrer com SQL Injection, porém, o formato que é usado para gravar dados no MongoDB (BSON) é um formato onde a sua query é interpretada como um objeto e não como string, por tanto é livre de SQL Injection.

Algumas outras diretivas podem ser tomadas para tornar mais difícil um possível SQL Injection como:

1) Colocar no seu arquivo de configuração no lado servidor a diretiva "security.javascriptEnabled"

2) Usar com cautela os comandos "$where" "db.eval()" "mapReduce" e "group" pois eles permitem rodar javascript arbitrário

3) Escapar nos seus inputs os operadores reservados "$" e "."

4) Caso use PHP junto com o Mongo, vc pode olhar este link com várias dicas de segurança http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongo.security.php

Referência em http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection

Espero ter ajudado.